# Keep Selenium Webdriver across Celery Tasks

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, celery

I developed a Flask web app that uses Celery to handle tasks. One of these tasks consists of scraping a bunch of pages (around 200) using a custom Class derived from a selenium chrome driver.

```
@celery_app.task
def scrape_async():
   driver = MyDriver(exec_path=os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'), options=some_chrome_options)
   
   # Update 'urls_to_scrape' attribute by finding the urls to scrape from a main url
   driver.find_urls_to_scrape_from_main_url()
   
   # Loop over each page and store the data in database
   for url in driver.urls_to_scrape:
      driver.scrape_page(url)

  # Exit driver
  driver.quit()
```

This worked well both in local and in production until the number of pages to scrape increased. I received a memory usage error on Heroku and realized how memory intensive the task was.

After some research, I found out that it would be easier to use a subtask in my loop (i.e. running this subtask for each page), as described below.

```
@celery_app.task
def subtask(url):
  driver.scrape_page(url)

@celery_app.task
def scrape_async():
   driver = MyDriver(exec_path=os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'), options=some_chrome_options)
   
   # Update 'urls_to_scrape' attribute by finding the urls to scrape from a main url
   driver.find_urls_to_scrape_from_main_url()
   
   # Loop over each page and store the data in database
   for url in driver.urls_to_scrape:
      subtask.delay(url)

  # Exit driver
  driver.quit()
```

My concern is about how to keep the driver object between the main task and the subtask.
I found this [link](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#instantiation), on how to instantiate Task but I couldn't manage to create one driver across multiple tasks.

Any idea on how to proceed to achieve my goal?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a selenium grid if you are using distributed crawling by doing so you will reduce the amount of resource usage for loading, rendering htmls, executing the js script to other server.

And in doing so you dont need to bother about the stuffs to be picked by the worker if you are using tasks backend if you are crawling nested links, multiple nested pages can be crawled by multiple workers independently and required mata data can be passed using results backend with group chains and chords functionality in celery.